# Rest API with a search function to display result in JSON format

Tags: python, api

I have to create an API in Python with a search function to display the results in JSON format. Here is the code which I have made, it is working but now I want to search by using 'name' not an 'id'. So how the code will be changed?

```
       import flask
       from flask import request, jsonify
       app = flask.Flask(__name__)
       app.config["DEBUG"] = True


      # Create some test data for our catalog in the form of a list of 
      dictionaries.
      employee = [
      {'id': 0,
       'name': 'deepak',
       'dept': 'it',
       'place': 'delhi',
       'phone number': '451992'},
      {'id': 1,
       'name': 'deepika',
       'dept': 'hr',
       'place': 'gurgaon',
       'phone number': '541992'},
      {'id': 2,
       'name': 'aryan',
       'dept': 'finance',
       'place': 'delhi',
       'phone number': '777992'}
]


      @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
      def home():
      return '''<h1>Distant Reading Archive</h1>
             <p>A prototype API for distant reading of science fiction 
              novelssadd.</p>'''


      @app.route('/api/v1/resources/employee/all', methods=['GET'])
      def api_all():
      return jsonify(employee)


      @app.route('/api/v1/resources/employee', methods=['GET'])
      def api_id():
      # Check if an ID was provided as part of the URL.
      # If ID is provided, assign it to a variable.
      # If no ID is provided, display an error in the browser.
      if 'id' in request.args:
      id = int(request.args['id'])
      else:
         return "Error: No id field provided. Please specify an id."

      # Create an empty list for our results
        results = []

      # Loop through the data and match results that fit the requested 
        ID.
      # IDs are unique, but other fields might return many results
        for emp in employee:
         if emp['id'] == id:
           results.append(emp)

      # Use the jsonify function from Flask to convert our list of
      # Python dictionaries to the JSON format.
        a= jsonify(results)
        return a

        app.run()
```

Using http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/books/all after running the code will display all the entries.

To search by name, this link has to be used: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/books?name=deepak 
Change the name at the end of the link to search.

Comment: It could be just a typo but you have some syntax errors.  For example, `id = int(request.args['id'])` should be indented.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `id` variable into your `api_id()` method somehow.  Take a look at [Flask variable rules](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#variable-rules) to see you can do it using Flask.  For a more in depth explanation check out [Designing RESTful apis with Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask)

Your code would look something like:

```
@app.route('/api/v1/resources/employee/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def api_id(id):
    # the rest of your code
```

Comment: Please let me know how to execute the code. (Shall i use simple run command to execute the code or there is some other way)

Comment: If you are seeing the `* Restarting with stat` on your console then you are running it correctly.  Open a web browser and goto http://127.0.0.1:5000 You should see the message you are returning in the `home()` function.  If that works, try http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/employee/all  and see what you get.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/employee/all  when I run it, then it is showing -> 'The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.'

Comment: If `/` works but `/api/v1/resources/employee/all` doesn't, I would start by looking at your console.  Maybe there is an error there.  After fixing the syntax errors I was able to run your code without issues.

Comment: Just want to ask, how the code will be changed if I want to search by using 'name' instead of 'id'.